# Python distutils - copy_tree with filter

Tags: python, file, distribution, py2exe, distutils

I want to copy a data directory into my distribution dir. `copy_tree` does this just fine. However, the project is also an svn repository, and I don't want the distribution to have all the .svn files that the data dir has. Is there any easy way to do a `copy_tree` excluding the `.svn` files, or should I just write my own recursive dir copy? I feel someone must have had this issue before.

Comment: Any reason not to use data_files or package_data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used `shutil.copytree`, which takes an `ignore` kwd arg.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code snippet:**

```
from distutils import file_util, dir_util

orig_copy_file = file_util.copy_file
orig_copy_tree = dir_util.copy_tree

def my_copy_file(src, *args, **kwargs):
    if src.endswith('.ext'):
        return
    orig_copy_file(src, *args, **kwargs)

def my_copy_tree(src, *args, **kwargs):
    if src.endswith('foldername'):
        return []
    return orig_copy_tree(src, *args, **kwargs)

file_util.copy_file = my_copy_file
dir_util.copy_tree = my_copy_tree
```